# Git: remove already ignored and removed from cache files from IntelliJ Changelist

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Already use many time command `git rm --cached -r .idea` and already added `.idea` dir to `.gitignore` but still this files in IntelliJ Changelist and waiting to commit:

[image: idea git commit]

What is the status of these files in git?
How to remove this files from this Changelist without removing files from file system?

Answer (score 2):

Once you have run `git rm --cached -r .idea`, you have to run `git commit`.

If you look more closely at your GUI, you can see that there is a "23 deleted" mentioned above the commit message input field.

---

If adding the `.idea/` directory was a mistake you did in your very last commit, and you want to do as if you had never added it, you can run `git commit --amend` (or tick the "Amend" checkbox in your GUI).

This will rewrite your last commit.